# Nullable object must have a value

Tags: c#

Am getting this error when l tried to add data in my project.it point me to this code:

```
var currentuserid = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
var user = db.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == currentuserid);
List<Claim> claims = db.Claims.Include("Claim_Status").Include("Patient").Include("Hospital").ToList();
var userClaims = claims.Where(c => c.Hospitalid.Value == user.Hospitalid);
return View(userClaims.ToList());
```

how can l solve this problem.

am using Microsoft sql server 2008.

Comment: how can l remove the duplicate nullable object.

Answer (score 1):

One or more of your `HospitalId`s are null. You can fix it by changing your `Where` clause to:

```
var userClaims = claims.Where(c => c.Hospitalid == user.Hospitalid);
```

which will filter out any claims with a null `HospitalId`.

Note that you're currently loading the entire `Claims` table and filtering the collection in memory. You probably want to execute the filter on the database, which you can do with:

```
List<Claim> claims = db.Claims.Include("Claim_Status").Include("Patient").Include("Hospital")
    .Where(c => c.HospitalId == user.Hospitalid)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: lee,thank u but l removed the `value` but the error still stays.

Comment: @UmarBachena - Which line is the exception on? It looks like `Hospitalid` is the only possible nullable value in your code.

Comment: it's on `Line 37:  var userClaims = claims.Where(c => c.Hospitalid == user.Hospitalid);`

Comment: @UmarBachena - Is it the same exception? Or is `user` null?

Comment: `Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.`

Comment: @UmarBachena - That code shouldn't throw an exception on a nullable value. Have you rebuilt everything?

Comment: @UmarBachena - Ok, then no match was found in your `UserProfiles` query, so you'll have to fix that first.

Comment: l rebuilt it but it still point me to the same error, how can l fix that in my `UserProfiles` query.

Comment: Lee, how can l fix this in my userprofiles?

Comment: @UmarBachena - Your query is probably ok, but the value returned by `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` does not correspond to a record in your database, so I can't really help you with that.

Comment: l understand u.thank you Lee.